# Using existing bundleid for rewrite of IOS App

Tags: ios

Having a major rewrite of my app on the AppStore but don’t want to change the name of it. I assume if I use the existing Apps bundleId it will update the app on AppStore, also read somewhere that when submitting updated App I need to tell Apple it’s a major change is this correct?

Comment: No, you do not need to tell Apple it's a rewrite. It's irrelevant to them.

Comment: But I can just reuse the bundle id for the new project?

Comment: That's all you need.